# Use the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus to find a solution to the initial value problem

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Let's consider the initial value problem: $ dy/dx = x - 2, y =(0) = 1 $.

Part 1 is to find the equation of the tangent line at x = 0 which is $y = -2x + 1$.

Part 2 I am given 3 more tangent lines:
(1, -0.5) has a slope of - 1
(2, -1) has a slope of 0
(3, -0.5) has a slope of + 1

And instructed to sketch a graph of the solution y(x) so that these lines are tangent to y(x).

And tracing along the tangent lines I realize the equation for this curve is $0.5x^2 - 2x + 1$.

The last part is to use the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus to find f(x), the solution to this initial value problem and compare to the one I sketched in part 2. I guess I'm not sure what my textbook is asking.

Anti-differentiating $ dy/dx = x - 2$ gets me $0.5x^2 - 2x + C$

This is the FTC in my book:

f
  (
  1
  )
  −
  f
  (
  0
  )
  =
  
    ∫
    0
    1
  
  
    f
    ′
  
  (
  x
  )
  
    
  
  d
  x
  .

FTC helps me find signed area under curve. Is this somehow supposed to help me calculate that C is equal to 1?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Ok, added some clarification and verbatim prompt from my textbook.

Answer (score 0):

From earlier in the textbook, if we have an initial point, we can plug it back in to find the value of C.

For this problem, we know $y(0) = 1$ and anti differentiating $dy/dx$ gives us y so we can set 1 =  0.52−2+, plugging in 0 for x, the first two terms become 0 and we are left with 1 = C which is the same equation from sketching the tangent lines/figuring out that it is a parabola centered at 2,-1.